# How can I retrieve the name of an element using getElementById?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have several href elements with the same id.  I would like to set a variable with the name of the href elements. I have tried these with no luck, returns null:

```
   var x = document.getElementById('y').getAttribute('name');
```

and

```
   var x = document.getElementById('y').name;
```

What am I missing?

Comment: *"with the same id"* <- that's what you're missing, you can only have one as ID's are unique

Comment: And if it's still returning `null` chances are you're trying to get the elements before they are available.

Comment: Ah, fiddle sticks! I have to re-think my approach it seems.  Thank you!

Comment: Why not use a class which can be assigned to multiple elements on the webpage?

Comment: Also, consider spelling fiddlesticks in the more conventional, single-word method.

Comment: I am not on my game today it seems, fiddlesticks.

Answer (score 0):

You *should* *not* have elements with the same ID, that kind of goes against what an ID means.

That said, using jQuery, you can look up the elements with a selector.

**This answers your question -- but please don't actually do this**

var $list = $("[id='y']");

Comment: Thank you, I am a dope, I can just pass the variable when calling the function, sometimes I over think things.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter pointed out, IDs are unique, so your logic is a bit flawed. What I recommend you use instead are classes. Those need not be unique and you can get them with a similar function like this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(names);
```

taken from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByClassName